SignalR client keeps sending empty objects messages to server(How to track and log them)

As you can see in the picture, the client keeps sending empty objects messages to the server every 10 seconds, and I want to log these messages.
How can I track it?
By logging these messages, I can determine which user is currently active for sending my server to client message.
I'm using ASP.NET MVC(.NET Framework 4.7.2).

These are heartbeat messages. Take a look at this answer and see if it's what you're looking for. That being said, if you maintain a list of connected clients (using the OnConnected method for capturing their connection ID) you'll have a list of every connected client.

Yeah, Thank you. I think by using GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<ITransportHeartbeat>().GetConnections().FirstOrDefault(c=>c.ConnectionId == connection.ConnectionId).IsAlive, it should be determined whether the last of these messages was successfully sent or not? And if it wasn't successful, then the SignalR engine itself will try to use the reconnect functionality to establish the connection again.
